# Nextcloud Static IP address slowing down the website

Tags: ip, static-ip, nextcloud

I installed Nextcloud on my Ubuntu 20.04 VM. Everything is working nicely, webpage is fast, the server gets the network credentials from DHCP server.

I want to change the IP address of my Nextcloud server (outside of the DHCP server range). All the network credentials are correct.

**sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml**
[Configuration file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTvUE.png)

Here’s the problem:

My server gets a new IP address but the webpage slows down by like 5x. The IP address I set is only used by the Nextcloud server.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could it rather be a DNS issue? Like, the DHCP lease is automatically coupled to a DNS entry, but your fixed IP is not - and now the server tries to figure out its own name from DNS and fails only after some timeout?

Comment: I'm not really sure what I should do about that.

Comment: I was thinking of setting that configuration back to normal (gets IP from DHCP). Then I'd go into DHCP server and give that Nextcloud VM MAC static IP from there?

Comment: If you have a closer look at my conf file it shows "renderer networkd" but I'm actually using netplan. Do I have to disable networkd somehow? If yes, how?

Comment: I just removed that line and my webpage is working really fast.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Paste the text into your question instead, so it's readable by screen readers and search engines.